# Updating table values using dropdown without using a submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update the database using a dropdown list without using a submit button.

Here's my dropdown:

```html
<td>
  <label for=""></label> 
  <select style="font-family: Questrial;" name="status" required>
   <option disabled selected hidden>Select Status</option>
   <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
   <option value="Closed: Cancelled">Closed: Cancelled</option>
   <option value="Closed: Solved">Closed: Solved</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Here's the script:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('option[name="status"]').click(function() {
      var status = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "update2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          status: status
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

And here's update2.php:

```js
<?php
//Insert Data
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $databasename = "companydb";
 
 try
 {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename",$username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
 if(isset($_POST["status"]))
 {
  $query = "INSERT INTO tickets(status) VALUES (:status)";
  $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
 array('status' => $_POST["status"])
 );
 
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
 if($count > 0)
 {
  echo "Data Inserted Successfully..!";
 }
  else
 {
  echo "Data Insertion Failed";
 }
 }
}

 catch(PDOException $error)
 {
  echo $error->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Basically what I want to happen is to update the table values when I make a selection from the dropdown list.

Currently, nothing happens when I make a selection. (No page reload, No error message, just nothing)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Also here's my table schema:

[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de79H.png)

Comment: replace `option[name="status"]` with `select[name="status"] option`

Comment: You should probably also listen to the `change` event instead of the click event to avoid running unnecessary code and making unnecessary requests.

Comment: @jeroen there are no unnecesary requests of you listen to click of the *options*. But it is better (usually done) with change event of select anyway.

Comment: can you make an alert `alert("clickListener works!");` at the very beginning of your click listener function and see if the alert shows?

Comment: @Cashbee Yes, I got the alert.

Comment: ok now insert alerts in ajax success handler, error handler (create one ;P), and one after ajax. in the ajax success handler you may also want to console.log the data. See which alerts show up one which don't.

Comment: @Cashbee True, but after you fix the problem you are probably not listening to clicks on the options any more. I would go for the select at least :-)

Comment: @JohnZ could it be that your stmt-execute line is missing a colon? try `:status` instead of `status`. I'm not a PDO expert but this could be the cause of your error

Comment: @Cashbee colon is optional here.

Comment: @Cashbee Still the same

Comment: have you done my approach with the alerts? what was the result?

Comment: @Cashbee Everything showed up, what does that mean?

Comment: If the alert in the ajax success handler was shown you should really console log your received data. Also, in the PHP file you may want to add an else-block for the `if(isset($_POST["status"]))` and echo "status not set". Last but not least, is there an element with the id "result" in your HTML?

Comment: @Cashbee I just noticed, I didn't have an element with the id "result" (LOL). Thank you so much! Currently, I'm getting `Field 'employee_id' doesn't have a default value`. But I guess I could figure that one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) change `$('option[name="status"]').click(` to `$('select[name="status"]').change(`
the name "status" is an attribute of the select, not the options.

2) make sure you have an element with the id "result", or else the ajax success handler will not insert the received data/string anywhere.

These changes should make your code work.

I recommend adding an error handler to every ajax call you do. Also try to prevent your php files that are called by ajax methods to have cases where nothing is returned / echoed.

```
if(isset($_POST["status"]))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tickets(status) VALUES (:status)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array('status' => $_POST["status"]));

    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if($count > 0)
    {
        echo "Data Inserted Successfully..!";
    }
        else
    {
        echo "Data Insertion Failed";
    }
}
// ! add else statement
else
{
    echo "unknown index: 'status'";
}
```

Also an interesting read about ajax error handling: [setting response codes in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting the wrong element
`$('option[name="status"]')` should be `$('select[name="status"] option'`

I suggest you to use id, they are more clear and faster.

In addition you will also be interested with the change event

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: with your code it listens to clicks on the select itself. might I suggest changing `$('select[name="status"]')`  to `$('select[name="status"] option')`. (But when the change event is used, listen to the select, not the option.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Cashbee Should I use `$('select[name="status"] option')`?

Comment: @JohnZ yes try it, but I fear it will not work. It is essentially the same as `$('select[name="status"]').change(..)` which you said in another comment does not work. Giving it a try is never wrong though.

Comment: @Cashbee Yes it didn't work, thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: @JohnZ in your ajax json try to rename the local variable status to localStatus for instance. (status: localStatus)

Comment: @Ananta And then what should happen?

Comment: Your parameter and your variable have the same name, maybe there is a confusion when trying to bind parameters.

Comment: IIRC naming the parameter the same as the variable works with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The selector should be `select` and the event should be [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/). Try this :

```
$('select[name="status"]').change(function() {
```

instead of :

```
$('option[name="status"]').click(function() {
```

Comment: Hm I did try this one but I still get the same result, thank you for pointing this out tho.

Comment: @JohnZ What's happen in your network panel of your console ? Any trace, any error ?

Comment: Nothing. The value of the dropdown just change, that's it.

Comment: @JohnZ Could you put a `console.log(status);` or  `alert(status)` after `var status = $(this).val();`?

Comment: @JohnZ I guess you have another javascript error. No error in your console (F12) ?

Comment: I've actually tried that, I didn't get anything. It's strange.